# Can I walk a file path (/foo/bar/baz) backward looking for a particular file in each directory in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I have a collection of cmake files I use to build a large number of projects. Currently, my cmake code doesn't support nested sub projects. In my build, each project installs its libraries into a top level directory called "devel_artifacts". Since all of the projects are currently at the same level, they each do something like this:

get_filename_component(DEVEL_INSTALL_PATH_PREFIX_ABSOLUTE "../devel_artifacts" ABSOLUTE)

to convert the relative ../devel_artifacts into an absolute path. To support nested sub projects I'd like to write a cmake function that looks in the current directory for devel_artifacts and if it doesn't find it, removes the final directory off the path and tries again... and keeps doing that until it either finds the path to devel_artifacts or fails (in which case it can simply terminate). Is this possible in cmake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build up a list of search paths starting from your current source dir and adding each parent iteratively, then pass that list to [`find_file`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_file.html):

```
set(SearchPath "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
while(NOT "${SearchPath}" STREQUAL "${PreviousSearchPath}")
  list(APPEND SearchPaths "${SearchPath}")
  set(PreviousSearchPath "${SearchPath}")
  # use legacy 'PATH' arg instead of 'DIRECTORY' for CMake version <= 2.8.11
  get_filename_component(SearchPath "${SearchPath}" DIRECTORY)
endwhile()

find_file(DevelArtifacts
          NAMES devel_artifacts
          PATHS ${SearchPaths}
          DOC "Path to devel_artifacts found by iterating up through dirs from ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
          NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```